# How do I *force* a Word 2013 document to a single language?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word 2013 document that's been translated from Thai to English.  Word insists that the text is in Thai and formats it accordingly.  Any new text I type will be in English.  If I select all and then set the language to English it stubbornly remains reporting that it is Thai.

Comment: Under Review -> Language -> Set Proofing Language, did you turn off automatically detect language?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy text to notepad, make new word document and then copy the text from notepad to the word.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did since this is only a three page document.  What do we do when we get a 10,000 page project.  While your answer is technically correct, I'll refrain from tagging it as such in the hope that I get a neater one.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be a problem even with document that size as well. But try ctrl+A, change the language.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Search and replace` command (Ctrl+H shortcut), click in `Select what` field, click on `More` button, `Format`--`Language`, select Thai

then click into `Replace with` field, `Format`--`Language`, select English

then press `Replace All`.